# Code running before fwrite finished (PHP)

Tags: php, session, fwrite

I'm trying to do a form of session tracking.

In the checkLogin.php, After the login process is successfully, it will write a small php array into a txt file with the user's name and also save the username as a session variable. which is later used to track whether the user is inactive. Via a Python script, if the user is inactive, the user's name will be removed from the array.

In any other web page, the web application will include the txt file and check if the username in the session variable is still in the array, and if it's not, it will destroy the session and prompt the user to log in agn (User has been inactive).

However, on the first login, when the application checks the array for the session username, it always returns not found for the first 1-2 seconds and change to found after. I think it's because the file is still writing as the applciation goes on to the next page. Is there a way to make the application wait for fwrite to complete before going to the next page?

After logging in, the text file (user.txt) will look like this

```
<?php activeUser= array("User1"); ?>
```

> "User1" is stored as $_SESSION['current_user']

In every other page, on the top of the code I have this

```
include 'user.txt';

if(in_array($_SESSION['current_user'], $activeUser))  {
    echo "Found";
    //User still active;
}
else {
    echo "Not Found";
    //session_destroy();
    //header("Location:index.php?status=userInactive");
}
```

Right after logging in and reach the home page with the 2nd chunk of code, it shows "Not Found", but after refreshing it changes to "Found".

Comment: Try to print array and the user session variable.Then see if they are different and then do the further debugging

Comment: @IshanMahajan The array written into the text file works perfectly, the text file consists an array of active users, so in theory, after logging in, it will check if the current user thats logged in (Session Variable) is in the array from the text file and should return Found, however I think the page is redirected too quickly before the fwrite is completed. I'm seeking a way to make the fwrite finish before redirecting.

Comment: Found a fix but I don't think it's very efficient. I placed a sleep(3) before the redirect on the checkLogin.php page. Seems like fwrite takes about 2-3seconds to complete. Any improvements would still be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Kelvin the code is not working as supposed and from the code you've provided all someone can guess is that the user is not there in the array.So all you need to do is to check both the array and session variable by printing it.Hence it is the only way

Comment: Apologies, When printing session variable, the correct user comes out, but when I print the array, on the first load it shows an empty array (before fwrite), and if i refresh it after 1 second, the array comes out with the current user in it (correct output). Hence, I narrowed it down to the fwrite as the fault, fwrite does not complete before the page redirects. I'm looking for a way to only redirect after fwrite has completed in the login process script.

Answer (score 0):

What I've inferred from your comment is that you want your code to be in asynchronous so try using try catch block.

```
        try {
            // try your time taking process here

        } catch(Exception $e) {
            // throw your failed case here
        }finally{ 
           // do the successfull case here
        }
```

Comment: Didn't work :( it seems the only way is the put a sleep delay before the redirect :/, finally clause doesn't wait for fwrite to finish before running, thanks for trying anyways :)